# Query last user activity

Tags: apex, site.com, logout

We are writing a custom ending session code for our Site.come community. What we want to do is to query trough Apex the datetime of the last activity of the user logged in.

There is in Salesforce an object that stores information like UserId, datetime of activity (API calls, UI interactions ecc...)?

Our idea is to call the last activity datetime and if it's out of a certain limit (eg. now plus ten minutes) use logout.jsp to force the log out of the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can do somthing like this

```
CustomSession__c customSession = [select Id, LastActivityDateTime__c from CustomSession__c where UserId__c =:currentLoggedInUserId order by LastActivityDateTime__c desc limit 1 ];

if(Datetime.now() > customSession.LastActivityDateTime__c.addMinutes(10)){
 //call logout page
}
```

Comment: I did it, using jquery cookie library. Thank you for help